# send email in laravel on localhost server

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I try to send emails in laravel on localhost MySql and I received this error:

```
Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 298: Process could not be started [The system cannot find the path specified.]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It will throw error. If you want to test in local server then you need to put **die** in your email template. Suppose you created one email in emails folder i.e test-email.blade.php and if you want to see that email:-

```
Enter Email Content here
<?php echo "test"; die; ?>
```

Hope it helps!